# What is the difference between an "Entry" and a "Context Entry" in ApacheDS/LDAP?

Tags: ldap, apache-ds

When creating a new entry in an ApacheDS LDAP directory with Apache Directory Studio, it gives the option of creating a `New Entry` or a `New Context Entry`.

[image: A screenshot showing the choice between New Entry and New Context Entry in Apache Directory Studio]

What is the difference between a *Context Entry* and a regular *Entry*?

Apologies if the answer is obvious, but I have searched Google for multiple hours with multiple permutations of search terms, and scoured the Apache Directory Studio documentation, but could not come to a clear or satisfactory answer. What I did find were tutorials warning to create one over the other, but not specifying as to *why*, leading me to believe that the difference is important.

I've tried:

- Reading the documentation.

  - The documentation describes the process of how to use the wizard to create each type of entry, but it does not describe the types nor the difference between them.
- Reading items found on Google about LDAP in general to see if there is an entry type of *Context Entry*.

  - "Context Entry" does not seem to be a typical LDAP term.
- Making both types of entry and comparing them.

  - After creating both types of entry, they *appear* to be identical, but they presumably must not be, otherwise why call them different things?

The only thing I've learned is that the difference between the creation of the two types is that a regular Entry helps you build a `dn` via two pieces, and the other accepts a single `dn` string in its entirety. Surely *that* cannot be the only difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on reading the ApacheDS Basic User Guide section "Adding a partition" and its many uses of "context entry", it is:

1. The first entry in a partition.
2. A namingContext in the Root DSE.
3. In a partition, the context entry is the root / "parent" under which all subsequent entries are added.
4. The value in a JDBM partition assigned to partition's "ads-contextEntry" property.
5. May be objectClass domain or organization.  Possibly others.

Example of a reference to ApacheDS Basic User Guide's use of the term "context entry": "Before using the partition (e.g. adding entries), you have to add a context entry."

So, then, the difference between an entry and a context entry is not a *what* but a *when*; use the Context Entry when creating the first/root entry of a partition, and a simple Entry to add new entries under a context entry or its sub-entries.